# Python Excel rows with same value checking

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I’m trying get my Python program to verify an excel spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: Example of my spreadsheet]

The first column is the order number and there may be one or more rows with the same number. Then there's the last column which indicates the row status (OK or not).

I want to check if all rows for a given order number have been
marked as OK.

I have found something called *pandas* and if anyone could give me a help with idea how to handle it? There's also an option called `groupby` - could I use this to group by order numbers and then verify if all rows for this order number have been marked as OK?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Just import the data and pivot it using pandas and check if number of empty counts are > 0. I used a dummy data since I couldn't take from your image:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['no'] = [1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3]
df['ok'] = ['OK','Empty','OK','Empty','Empty','OK','OK','OK']
df['cnt'] = 1

a = df.pivot_table(index=['no'],columns=['ok'],values='cnt', aggfunc='count')
a.reset_index(inplace=True)
a.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print a
```